# I want to publish many apps of client in app store so which Apple Developer Program i have to buy?

Tags: ios, app-store, iphone-developer-program

I want to publish many apps of a client in AppStore so which Apple Developer Program I have to buy?? Apple Developer Program (individual) Or Apple Developer Program (Organization) Or Apple Developer Enterprise Program??? Please suggest me in detail,how should i proceed?

Comment: Generally, it depends.  You'll need at least a individual membership, but if your writing Apps for a client/different company, then realistically, they should have a Organisation membership and you should be invited to join the team

Comment: but I have a company then i want to upload more apps then?

Answer (score 1):

**Individuals** or **sole proprietors/single person businesses**. Apps are sold on the App Store under the developer's personal name.

> This program is used generally by non IT businesses or smaller firms. Where firm has got their application developed to support/advertise their online business. Its cost is less than Organization account.
> I guess it suits you.

**Organizations**. Apps are sold on the App Store under the organization's legal entity name. Companies and educational institutions must provide a D-U-N-S Number (available for free) registered to their legal entity during the enrollment process.

> This program is used where firm has to publish, manage and handle
> dozens of apps, and it mostly deals in IT business. Organizations main
> products are software applications. It costs more than individual account.
>
> Enterprise account is used internally in an organization. Mostly
> bought by IT firms

For more information:
https://developer.apple.com/support/compare-memberships/

Comment: Apple Developer Program And Apple Developer Enterprise program What is the difference?

Comment: Apple developer organization Account  is 99$ and Apple Developer indivisual account also 99$ so which one to buy?

Comment: If your firm has registered itself as Legal entity (its legally a person) you can go for Organization account. Basically accounts ownership will be with company not with some individual in this case. Or in other case you can buy Individual account its ownership with be individual. Both can be used to publish applications.

Comment: Enterprise account is used to deploy applications at personal/private/organizational devices even without publishing applications within organization without adding UDIDs which are required in adhoc builds.